# Vuetify 3 layout issue: main area outside of app?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, web-frontend, vuetifyjs3

coming from vue js without components framework I recently discovered vuetify.
But I cant get my head around the layout logic.

Starting from the example right after
`npm create vuetify`

i tried to layout my application as following:
[image]

What my problem is now that the table component gets rendered not in the main space istead outside of v-app?
[image]

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup>
  //
</script>
```

**AppBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar flat color="primary">
    <v-app-bar-title>
      <v-icon icon="mdi-circle-slice-6" />

      ISV Application
    </v-app-bar-title>
  </v-app-bar>
  <v-card >
    
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :rail="rail"
      permanent
      @click="rail = false"
    >
      <v-list-item
        prepend-avatar="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"
        title="John Leider"
        nav
      >
        <template v-slot:append>
          <v-btn
            variant="text"
            icon="mdi-chevron-left"
            @click.stop="rail = !rail"
          ></v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list density="compact" nav>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-home-city" title="Home" value="home"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account" title="My Account" value="account"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account-group-outline" title="Users" value="users"></v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main style="height: 250px"></v-main>
  
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    data () {
      return {
        drawer: true,
        rail: true,
      }
    },
  }
  //
</script>
```

**DefaultLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <default-bar />
    
    <default-view />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import DefaultBar from './AppBar.vue'
  import DefaultView from './ViewLayout.vue'
</script>
```

**HomeView.vue**

```
<template>
    <PlanesTable />
</template>

<script setup>
  //import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
  import PlanesTable from '@/components/PlanesTable.vue'

  
</script>
```

**ViewLayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-main >
    <v-container>
      <router-view />
  </v-container>
  </v-main>
</template>

<script setup>
  //
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
// Composables
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('@/layouts/default/DefaultLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Home',
        // route level code-splitting
        // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
        // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/views/HomeView.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

export default router
```

Any ideas what I am missing?
Thank you for your thougts.
Greets

Comment: Does it work when you remove the v-card around the v-navigation-drawer and v-main in AppBar.vue? I don't know how the posted files go together, but there usually is only one v-main. The particular behavior of layout components like VAppBar, VNavigationDrawer and VMain has it's on [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/)

Comment: Sharp eye! Thank you, I cleaned up the tags as you suggested. Works fine now. 
Thank you very much!